# How to store a table to database in Django 2.1?

Tags: html, django

I have a table inside html, and I need to save it into database using view and model and form. Here are some part of the code:

**template.html**

```
<form method="post" action="/images/save/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table" border="1" id="tbl_posts">
    <tbody id="tbl_posts_body">

    {% for name, age in lines %}
    {% with i=forloop.counter0 %}
    {% with i|add:1|stringformat:"s" as i_id %}
    {% with id="rec-"|add:i_id %}

    <tr id={{id}}>
        <td><span class="sn">{{ i|add:1 }}</span>.</td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt1" value=""\></td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2" value=""\></td>
    </tr>

    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**model.py:**

```
class Names(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age= models.IntegerField()
```

**view.py:**

```
def save_form(request):
    template = "template.html"
    context = {'txt1': "Name", 'txt2': 0}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dname= request.POST.get("txt1")
        dage= request.POST.get("txt2")
        names1= Names(name=dname, age=dage)
        names1.save()

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Question:**
So, it works perfectly, but the issue is that It saves only the last row. I think there is a way to enter the whole data. I need to enter all data in the table not only the last row. Can someone help me?

Update:
lines is a zip a combination of two lists, I read it from a file.

Comment: You are sending only one record to view.py. Pass all values to view.py and use for loop to save data or bulk_create to save data.

Comment: I guess you should read about forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Comment: I guess you could also try using `request.POST.getlist("txt1")`, but I'm not sure if there're any ordering guaranees. The proper django way would be to use a formset though.

Comment: Thanks, Can Use <tr id={{id}}> to send all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are the ones which get sent in a form.

```
<td><INPUT type="text" name="txt1" value=""\></td>
<td><INPUT type="text" name="txt2" value=""\></td>
```

However, you are using the same "names" to send the values for multiple rows.The result of that is that you will only get those values once with the current code you have in your view. You will want to give each of them a unique name (just do something like this:

```
<td><INPUT type="text" name="txt{{forloop.counter}}" value=""\></td>
```

and then iterate through them in your view.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but I would like to save according to <tr id={{id}}>, can I do that?

Comment: You could use id to set the variable names of the inputs. So name="txt{{id}}1" and name="txt{{id}}2"

Comment: yes, I did that, now I need to know the size of the elements to iterate inside views.py. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Would it not be the same as the number of names/ages? Is that not how many inputs there are?

Comment: no, loop may iterate many times for Name and age. I found a solution by iteration for big number inside view, so if there is no element at some point, it break the loop, but this is not good.